# Submit button `disabled`s itself

Tags: feature-request, form-submit

After clicking the submit button, it goes in "disabled" mode. Which is fine, except for when the submission does not complete for whatever reason.

Let's say my internet connection is prone to dying a lot.

If I submit a post when my connection is down, the submit button freezes, yet it doesn't submit. I'm presented with no obvious way to re-submit. The procedure that sort of works is: refresh (shows an error page), back (shows draft, check it), re-submit, $&#% CAPTCHA, finish. This one loads to the draft though. Of course, one can copy the text beforehand.

But that isn't too obvious for newbies.

What I propose is that after 5 seconds, the submit button should get a little red message under it "submit not working? [click here]" or something (maybe with a snippet on waiting for your connection). I know that this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) (due to double submit reasons, etc), so I'm making this a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

The main motivation for this request is: It's not obvious that we can refresh>back>blah (also cumbersome); and it leads to loss of post material due to it reverting to a draft.

Comment: +1 since a also suffer from an unreliable internet connection.